# Array function VB

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net

Im trying to use the Array function in VB, but every time I use it, the error appears. "array is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

```
excel.ActiveSheet.Range(range).RemoveDuplicates(Columns:=Array(1,2))
```

Comment: Array isn't a function, it's a Type. You'll have to initialize an array and pass that variable to the function.

Comment: Can you show your whole code? In general that line is (mostly) correct, but it depends on the code around it. I am unable to replicate your stated error "array is a type and cannot be used as an expression" with just that line alone, so i suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You appear to be using VBA code. Is it in fact VB.NET where you are trying to run it?

Comment: I´m using VB.Net while using this function from VBA Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
excel.ActiveSheet.Range(range).RemoveDuplicates(Columns:=New Object() {1,2})
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns argument takes an "array of indexes of the columns that contain the duplicate information". This is taken from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates). Try passing an array with those indexes.

```
excel.ActiveSheet.Range(range).RemoveDuplicates(Columns:=New Object() {1, 2})
```

Comment: The documentation is for VBA. Are you sure you pass correct array?